# Why do I get compilation errors in iterator_facade depending on where I put my Boost header includes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I'm attempting to incorporate Boost in my existing medium sized project. I have the precompiled header file, `stdafx.h`, where I keep all my C++ stdlib `#include` directives (plus some Windows headers), and many `.cpp` files which include `stdafx.h`, among them `A.cpp`. It includes `stdafx.h` in the very first line, then some other headers needed by that file only. I wanted to use `boost::program_options` in `A.cpp`, so I added this to the include list right after `stdafx.h`, so the top of `A.cpp` looked like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

// more #includes
```

I then proceeded to compile the project, but encountered the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2976   'boost::iterators::detail::postfix_increment_result': too few template arguments    testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  789
Error   C1903   unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation  testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  790
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '++'   testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  790
Error   C2059   syntax error: ','   testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  534
Error   C2059   syntax error: ','   testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  541
Error   C2059   syntax error: ','   testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  600
Error   C2059   syntax error: ','   testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  606
Error   C2059   syntax error: ','   testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  789
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  790
Error   C2433   'type': 'inline' not permitted on data declarations testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  790
Error   C2888   'if_<T1,T2,T3>::type type': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'iterators'   testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  790
Error   C2976   'boost::iterators::iterator_facade': too few template arguments testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  534
Error   C2976   'boost::iterators::iterator_facade': too few template arguments testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  541
Error   C2976   'boost::iterators::iterator_facade': too few template arguments testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  600
Error   C2976   'boost::iterators::iterator_facade': too few template arguments testProject C:\boost_1_59_0\boost\iterator\iterator_facade.hpp  606
```

I experimented a bit and found out that if I put

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
```

at the *very end* of `stdafx.h` - the last lines - everything compiles fine, but if I try to put it anywhere in `A.cpp`, I get the above errors. I don't really understand how this is possible; doesn't the preprocessor just perform mindless inserting, in which case the very same output should be fed to the compiler after the preprocessor does its job? What could the reason be? I have searched around but I only found posts by people who actually wanted to use `iterator_facade` and were getting errors in their code, not in Boost headers.

My config:
VS 2015 on Windows 8.1, Boost 1.59.0, x86 project, built with `/MT`

**UPDATE:** It also works if I include that header in both `A.cpp` and `stdafx.h`.

**UPDATE2:** Interestingly, this is what I have in my Output Window after compilation fails:

```
1>  INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe'
1>      Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>      Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is something like, one of your header files is missing include guards (or the include guard has a typo) and you are actually including some boost header twice. (Not all of the boost headers individually have include guards. The ones you are supposed to include do, but some of them just don't "for efficiency reasons" I'm told.)

Or, that you are including boost inside of a namespace somewhere, which is something it cannot really protect itself against.

This error `'boost::iterators::detail::postfix_increment_result': too few template arguments` is exactly what I would expect if it's some template definition and the compiler encountered the definition a second time.

Comment: The thing is, I only include this header once in the entire project and it doesn't work when it's included in a source file (`.cpp`), which obviously isn't included anywhere, so it's not really possible that the Boost header is included more than once.

Comment: Maybe not program options itself, but maybe this `iterator_facade` thing is, if you include other boost libs in other files they may also be including it implicitly.

Comment: Well, I've noticed that if I include it without including `stdafx.h` before, it works fine, so the problem must be there somewhere. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Also, this whole issue about precompiled headers shouldn't be relevant. If turning off precompiled headers / flushing your cache fixes the issue, then it just means that you had a stale cache and its an issue with your build system.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to give up, I wasted a few more hours and got absolutely nowhere, apart from realizing MSVC is reporting an ICE in addition to refusing to compile the code, which I feel shouldn't happen.